# Updating to 3.13.0-39 broke Mouse and Keyboard

Tags: 14.04, usb, keyboard, mouse, dell

**EDIT:** I finally realized that there are two different versions of Linux listed in the Grub booting menu

- 3.13.0-39
- 3.13.0-32

If I pick  `3.13.0-32` the keyboard and mouse will work. But if I pick `3.13.0-39` I have no mouse or keyboard.

Last week I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Optiplex 760. The whole install worked fine and I started getting everything on the machine set up to my liking (installing chrome, email client, mapping a shared drive). I rebooted several times during this process and had no issues.

I come back to it this morning and now I cannot get any keyboard or mouse to do anything inside of Ubuntu. I have tried different keyboards/mice and different USB ports all with no effect.

While the machine is booting up it does recognize keyboard and mouse because I can use them to press F2 which will take me to the BIOS and then I can navigate around the BIOS with both mouse and keyboard. So I know all of the hardware is working fine.

Searching around online I've found a lot of stuff talking about VT-d and enabling IOMMU but I don't see any option for anything by either of those names in the BIOS and I don't know enough about either of them to even know where else to start looking.

Since I can't get keyboard or mouse working I can't run any commands to help with diagnostics.

However I am able to boot from the install CD and alter files on the hard drive. I tried adding `intel_iommu=soft` to the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` based on a suggestion I found while searching for this issue and device model #. That does not seem to have had any effect though to be honest I am not certain I actually put it in the right spot.

Does any one have suggestions for further diagnosing or solving this issue so that I can correctly use mouse / keyboard on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been another new version of the kernel `3.13.0-40` which resolved the issue. Once my ubuntu updated to this new version everything went back to working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem whit mouse, and you could try to enter in the terminal this:

```
 gsettings set org.settings.gnome-cursor cursor=false
```

and for the keyboard enter this in the terminal:

```
 gsettings set org.settings.gnome-keyb keyb=true
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did not work unfortuantely